# Typing Accent Marker in Hebrew on Mac

Tags: macos, mac, fonts, hebrew, embedded-fonts

I'm learning ancient Hebrew and wanted to make a document full of the vocabulary words I need to memorize so that I can study during my other classes. I noticed that OSX's built-in Hebrew fonts do not include the accent marker.

An example: the word for "darkness" is חשֶׁךְ. To represent that the accent is on the first syllable, there needs to be a < over the first letter. The accent could be in the middle of the word, so I can't just throw < at the front every time.

Does anyone have a free font that includes this? Any other elegant solutions are welcome.

Edit: I found that it is unicode character 05AB. Is there a way to add that to the built-in Hebrew fonts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After snooping around and asking my professor, it seems like the most convenient way to type it in OSX is through the Character Viewer, which can be enabled by:

1. Go to System Preferences;
2. Language and Text;
3. Input Sources;
4. Check "Show Input menu in menu bar" at the bottom and check "Keyboard and Character Viewer" on the left.